# linux shell storing path

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to find the path of folder  and store it into a variable

```
 #!/bin/bash
 howdy=$(whereis yum.repos.d)
 howdy=$howdy"/remi.repo"
 echo $howdy
```

The issue is that when I want to use the variable $howdy , it will output

```
 yum.repos: /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
```

I want it to be just the path

```
 /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
```

so I could use it in my code

Comment: `whereis` ideally shouldn't return the `yum.repos: ` part. When I run `whereis` I only get output like `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`awk`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) to format the output:

```
howdy=$(whereis yum.repos.d| awk '{print $2}')
```

Full code:

```
#!/bin/bash
howdy=$(whereis yum.repos.d| awk '{print $2}')
howdy=$howdy"/remi.repo"
echo $howdy
```

this will output: `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo`

Answer (score 3):

You can erase the first part of the string:

```
echo ${howdy##*: }
```

Or you can pipe it through `cut -d' ' -f2`

Answer (score 3):

You can use Parameter Expansion:

```
${howdy#yum.repos: }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
howdy=$(find /etc -type f -name remi.repo)
```

Comment: He probably wouldn't need to use whereis in the first place if he knew the directory was in /etc.

Answer (score 0):

`whereis yum.repos.d | awk -F: '{print $2}'` will give strip off the first part